# Chat room list layout changes when zooming out

Tags: bug, chat

On the chat page, when I use zooming (ie, zoom page size to anything less than 100%) the box alignment of the chats shifts to a 3-column fit on webkit.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I can't reproduce this now.  (I realize it's been 5 years since the question was asked.)  The whole page zooms, preserving four columns, in both directions.  *Other* things break, but the number of columns doesn't change.  This is 6 zoom levels out:

[image: zoomed out]

Comment: Zoming in doesn't change the number of coloums either. A slider bar comes up but the number of columns still stays the same

Comment: That is weird... I checked both FF and Chrome (for Mac) on Sunday and the problem still existed then. See image here: [Sort "favorite" chat rooms by strict recent activity rather than by type of room](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/303452/284336)

Comment: @Catija huh, that's weird -- I just took that screenshot in Chrome on a Mac.  And I see the four columns + horizontal scrollbar all the time if I zoom in, on both Firefox (Mac and WIndows) and Chrome (Mac).  Oh, and tablet too, now that I think about it.  I've never seen a different number of columns.  I wonder what's different for you?

Comment: Yeah... :/ It doesn't reduce to three columns on Chrome for Windows, either... so I'm really confused now... :(

Comment: Well.. balpha is now in active bug watch duty, so maybe he silently fixed it. /cc @Catija. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Stack Exchange does not support zooming, as officially said [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/296008/152859):

> We do not support zooming - either in or out.

<sub>(Post author was SE employee/developer when writing that answer)</sub>

So, this bug is most likely [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) as well.