# Zoom gestures break hover

Tags: bug, status-declined, mac, zoom

On MacBook, I like to zoom using gestures on my trackpad, as described here:

> With a Multi-Touch trackpad or Magic Mouse, you can tap, swipe, pinch, or spread one or more fingers to perform useful actions.
>   <sub>[Use Multi-Touch gestures on your Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204895)</sub>

(This is different than zooming with <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> or <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd>.)

However, when I do this, many hover events don't work right. Like tag hover (and profile popup):

> [image]

Here's a gif: http://g.recordit.co/Ji4Sn48BVu.gif.

As I zoom in more, the popup moves further away from where it should be.

I also noticed that it breaks SEDE graph hover; nothing happens when I hover over a point. (It should show the Y value.)

I am able to see the hover text (as in `[description](example.com "hover text")`) properly.

Comment: Zoom is not supported, IIRC so it can't be a bug. The sites are designed to be looked at 100% and 100% only.

Answer (score 5):

We do not support zooming - either in or out.

Comment: but why?..........