# Why doesn't the site banner support zooming?

Tags: discussion, top-bar, responsive-design, fixed-width, zoom

I understand that a common feature like zooming can be complicated enough to be [not supported](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/296008/260800), but why can't the site banner zoom too? If the black top bar can be made screen-fit, and the fact that the reputation and badges disappear when zooming suggests that this particular bar is supported, then why can't the site banner be? There are plenty room for the buttons, and I think the HTML element is basic enough to make it easy.

## Before

[image]

## After

Zoom at 133%
[image]

Comment: Zoom is not supported by Stack Exchange. (So you can find and report about 1000 bugs with it, but they won't be fixed. Just don't zoom.)

Comment: I've edited the question. Also, do you know why it deserves a downvote?

Comment: I downvoted because your question implies SE should support zoom, and I disagree with this. As for edit, well, top bar is still part of the site, it's not some external third party widget. So what applies to the site in general, applies to the top bar as well.

Comment: I see. But the black bar is not a part of the site? Also this is not a duplicate anymore, no?

Comment: How is it not part of the site?? It is just an element in the page, which happens to be the same anywhere on Stack Exchange.

Comment: because the black bar supports zoom and the site bar is not?

Comment: Wait... you mean **resize**,  not zoom. That's something totally different. Please edit your question to reflect this. (TL;DR: it's by design, part of responsive design.)

Comment: what's the difference? It seems that [`zoom vs resize`](https://www.google.com/search?q=zoom+vs+resize&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b) are the same

Comment: Zooming (often) does a variety of things including making the text size larger, among other things. Resizing is a matter of making the pixel width of the page smaller or larger. If you're using the "Zoom" option in the menu bar (or with key combos), that's a zoom. If you're dragging the sides or bottom of the browser window in/out or up/down, that's resizing.

Comment: @Catija I see. But well, it's about zooming. I use the `Ctrl +` or `Ctrl -` to zoom it.

Comment: If you try it on SO or here, zooming works with the new responsive design (to some degree), so I think the answer is the same, regardless of which you're talking about. I'd edit your question to point out the specific zoom levels of those two images to point things out more clearly.

Comment: No repro (Firefox).  I tried ctrl-+ and ctrl-- on both MSE and another (non-SO) site, and the top bar responded by changing font sizes and pushing elements farther left or right.  What's your window width?

Comment: @MonicaCellio it's maximized. Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, try it here on MSE and you'll find that it's not just the black top bar that's responsive. Because the top bar is now the same (almost) everywhere, it seems that the DAG team has already made it responsive, despite the fact that not all sites have the responsive design yet. The network is in the process of [implementing responsive design](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/307862/ch-ch-ch-changes-left-nav-responsive-design-themes) everywhere on the network. So, in a few months, your problem will no longer *be* a problem.

Until then, enjoy the responsive top bar and the fact that both Meta Stack Exchange and Stack Overflow/Meta Stack Overflow are responsive (mostly). They're still in middle stages, so there will be some interim time while they make parts of the site (such as the ask question page and profile pages) responsive... and then, eventually... the entire network!