# Share box becomes blurry if not at 100% zoom level

Tags: bug, design, user-interface, zoom

Today, I found out browsing SE can simulate a visit to the optometrist. Which one looks clearer to you?

The share box at 90 percent zoom:

[image]

At 100 percent:

[image]

Or the one at 110 percent:

[image]

Opening a share box when your page isn't zoomed to 100 percent will result in a blurry pop up, at least for Google Chrome (76.0.3809.132).

Comment: Related https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/296008/312043

Comment: @Arulkumar If that's still the case, then that's probably it, but zooming and hovering over tags seems to work/be supported now...So I'm wondering if something changed between then and now.

Comment: That doesn't happen in my Opera 63.

Comment: That happens to me on Chrome, exactly the same version as yours (also on version 77.0.3865.75 that I just updated), doesn't happen on Edge for example so probably an update changed something.

Comment: Wasn't the companies stance that the site doesn't support zoom? Or in other words: glitches caused by a zoom-level other then 100% are status-by-design ie status-nofix.

Comment: @rene curious to see if that's still the case... Arulkumar already linked me to an answer saying that from 2 years ago, but that was since fixed it seems (I can zoom in and the tag hovering still works)

Comment: @Tinkeringbell it could have been an incidental fix.

Comment: @rene that would be an extremely hostile, anti-accessible position for them to take today, so I hope they have revised their thinking on that.  (I noticed this fuzziness too but didn't figure out that it was tied to zoom.)

Comment: @MonicaCellio yeah, well ... maybe I'm a bit harsh. This particular bug only exists on Chrome, and only when the viewport is scrolled. It is caused by how SE uses the CSS and IIRC the jury is still out if the CSS3 specs are unclear or Chrome screwed up. Use IE11 to not have that problem ;)

Comment: IE11 doesn't work well on my Mac.  (Possibly those last three words are unnecessary.)

Comment: @MonicaCellio the no-zoom policy was mentioned by a staff some time ago, particularly when SE didn't have responsive design.

Comment: @MetaAndrewT. yeah, I'm hoping that's no longer SE's policy.  Old statements don't necessarily get updated, after all.

Comment: It's no-repro on FF Android, here's the [share pop-up zoomed in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/czAOP.jpg) on a 4K screen, it's tack sharp. It's browser or OS specific.